# nginx: react native url refresh leads to 404

Tags: react-native, nginx, http-status-code-404

also after googling quite a bit I was not able to find the solution. I'm running a Plesk for Ubuntu and am currently deploying a react native app. All url-paths checkout fine and navigation within the app works. However if I'm for instance on www.mydomain.com/something/something and I refresh the page the refresh leads to a 404 error.

What I tried now

I ssh'ed into `/var/www/vhosts/system/mydomain.com/conf` and udpated the file `nginx.conf` with

```
server {
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
        }
}
```

I restarted the service, however this does not do the trick.

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks
Matt

Here is the full nginx.conf file:

```
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

server {
        listen 175.31.15.213:443 ssl http2;

        server_name example.com;
        server_name www.example.com;
        server_name ipv4.example.com;
        server_name "example.com.52-29-213-14.svr.fm";

        ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/certXTrwD4;
        ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/certXTrwD4;
        ssl_client_certificate      /opt/psa/var/certificates/certL2SKRF;

        client_max_body_size 128m;

        root "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs";
        access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
        error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

        if ($host ~* ^1519\.tirol$) {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
        }

        #extension letsencrypt begin
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

                types { }
                default_type text/plain;

                satisfy any;
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;

                location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge.*/\. {
                        deny all;
                }
        }

        #extension letsencrypt end

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://175.31.15.213:7081;
                proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
                access_log off;

        }

        location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
                alias /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/;
                internal;
        }

        location ~ ^/(plesk-stat|awstats-icon|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat) {
                proxy_pass https://175.31.15.213:7081;
                proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
                access_log off;

        }

        location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
                alias /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/;
                internal;
        }

        location ~ ^/(plesk-stat|awstats-icon|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat) {
                proxy_pass https://175.31.15.213:7081;
                proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
                access_log off;

        }

        location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
                alias /var/www/vhosts/example.com/web_users/$1/$2;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock";
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

        }

        location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
                proxy_pass https://175.31.15.213:7081;
                proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
                access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock";
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

        }

        location ~ /$ {
                index "index.html" "index.cgi" "index.pl" "index.php" "index.xhtml" "index.htm" "index.shtml";
        }

        add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;

        include "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
}

server {
        listen 175.31.15.213:80;

        server_name example.com;
        server_name www.example.com;
        server_name ipv4.example.com;
        server_name "example.com.52-29-213-14.svr.fm";

        client_max_body_size 128m;

        if ($host ~* ^1519\.tirol$) {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
        }

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
        }
}
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T` to view the full configuration. Is there another `server` block? Because, the server block in your question should not generate a 404 response.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks, I updated my question above. Maybe I'm updating the wrong file generally. Not an expert with this. But all I know is right now a page-refresh of a uri results in a 404, rest works fine.

Comment: The service on port 7081 appears to be handling the request and is probably responsible for the 404 status. I cannot help with that.

Comment: Does anybody know what 7081 service does?